# Force required to move a liquid through a specified opening

Tags: forces, fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram, viscosity

If I know the rate of a liquid, the density of that liquid, the velocity of the liquid, and the size of the opening. How would I calculate the force required (in PSI) to move that liquid through the opening, or is that not how it's done?

- The rate is 5.5 gpm
- Density is 1 g/cm³
- The size of the opening is 0.25 in²
- Velocity is 35.95 feet per second
  My liquid is water, and I'm trying to use a water pump to pump water through a straight tube (no nozzle).

Comment: How did you make (or otherwise obtain) these measurements for rate, density, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key phrase you want to search on is *fluid flow through an orifice*.

It isn't simple.  In addition to the parameters you gave, it depends on *at least* the following:

- The shape of the orifice, in three dimensions (a simple hole in an infinitely thin flat plate will flow less than a perfectly shaped nozzle).
- The viscosity of the fluid.
- Whether the fluid must be treated as compressible, and whether the flow exceeds the local speed of sound (I don't *think* these are one and the same for flow through an orifice, but I don't *know*).
- The Reynolds number (which relates velocity, viscosity, density, and the size of the orifice.  It basically means that results for teeny orifices may not scale directly by area to results for large ones for the same pressure difference)

The hard way to find an answer: get a degree in physics or mechanical engineering with a specialty in fluid dynamics.

The easy way to find an answer: find a handbook (they're out there, on the web even), fit your problem to a table in the handbook, and get an approximate answer.